# How can a gulp task know if a gulp.watch task is running?

Tags: git, gulp, gulp-watch

I have a gulp git task that does a checkout, thus changes the current working dir.

I also have gulp watch tasks that recompile changed files.

I do NOT want to run the git task if any watch task is running .. it would recompile the files in the new branch.

Is there a way to detect if a gulp watch task is running?  If so I can simply exit the git task with a warning message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [gulp-if plugin](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-if) for this

Create a variable `isWatching` for instance, and when running your `watch` task, set it to `true`
Then, in your task that runs git you can do: `if(!isWatching, runGit)`, where runGit would be a function that executes your git task or whatever

---

## [PasteBin Example (for color coding)](http://pastebin.com/jZZTznKD)

Comment: I don't think this works because gulp would run a separate process for the two tasks (gulp watch& and gulp runGit).  I.e. the flag would have to be global somehow, right? .. or is there a way for gulp tasks to share variables?

Comment: Well, the gulpfile IS plain JS, so you could easily create a global variable and use that.

It's pretty much what I am doing to check if I have a `--prod` flag for instance, in which case I will conditionally run concatenation and minification of scripts

Comment: So let me make sure you are saying what I think you are: 1) run a watch task, in the background via "gulp watch&".  2) have that task set a global variable (i.e. in the global node space, what would be "window" in the browser).  3) run a separate gulp command, "gulp doGit" (w/o & .. it completes right away). 4) that task will somehow be able to see the variable set by 1)?  I don't see how without using something platform specific like an environment variable, it will have a new global namespace.

Comment: Not exactly what I meant but close to it. 
Like you I don't think this specific approach would work for the very reason you mentioned

You would need to consider running a single process at a time.
So doing `gulp watch` would need to do all the work, so to speak

Let me update my answer with an example (might take some time, I am busy with a nasty bug so please be patient :))

Comment: Added a quick example, let me know if it makes sense to you!

Answer (score 0):

Solving using environment variables

```
gulp.task("build-typescript", () => {
     if (process.env.IS_GULP_WATCH !== 'true') {
         // this is gulp watch
     }        
     else
     {
         // this is not gulp watch
     }
});

gulp.task('watch-typescript', () => {
    process.env.IS_GULP_WATCH = 'true';
    // watch files
});
```